# Change value of an already displayed Crouton

Tags: android, image, text, notifications, crouton

I was wondering if it is possible to change the text and the image of a crouton when it is already displayed. And how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the simple case you can't easily. However, I imagine if you provide a custom view and maintain a reference to it you could modify the view at will. Here are the custom view make methods:

```
public static Crouton make(Activity activity, View customView);
public static Crouton make(Activity activity, View customView, ViewGroup viewGroup);
public static Crouton make(Activity activity, View customView, int viewGroupResId);
public static Crouton make(Activity activity, View customView, int viewGroupResId, final Configuration configuration);
```

There are also corresponding show methods.

You might also be able to do it with the default view using `findViewById`. From the source, the IDs of the image and text are:

```
private static final int IMAGE_ID = 0x100;
private static final int TEXT_ID = 0x101;
```

You'll just have to make sure you search the correct view (sub)hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

No, not with standard, unmodified crouton lib